# Java mysql prepared statement update not working

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

This is my code:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from page");
PreparedStatement updatepage = mySqlCon.prepareStatement("update enwiki.page set enwiki.page.Text = ? where page_id = ?");
int count = 0;
while (rs.next())
{
     int id = rs.getInt("id");
     String text = rs.getString("text");
     if(text == null)
          text = "";
     updatepage.setString(1, text);
     updatepage.setInt(2, id);


     if(count++ > 10000)
     {
         updatepage.executeUpdate();
         updatepage.clearBatch();            
         count = 0;
      }
}

updatepage.executeUpdate();
```

The problem is after the line : `updatepage.executeUpdate()` is run, I check the database using workbench and I don't see any changes on that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is only executing the update when the value of `count` is greater than 10000, and it executes a single update. Seems like you want/need to use a batch processing, so you have to add the statements into the batch on every iteration (something you're not doing) and execute all the statements in the batch inside your `if` (something you're not doing either).

The code will be like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("id");
    String text = rs.getString("text");
    if(text == null)
        text = "";
    updatepage.setString(1, text);
    updatepage.setInt(2, id);

    //add the current statement to the batch
    updatepage.addBatch();
    if(count++ > 10000) {
        //line below will only execute the current statement (useless)
        //updatepage.executeUpdate();
        //line below will clear the batch statements (useless too)
        //updatepage.clearBatch();
        updatepage.executeBatch();
        count = 0;
    }
}
//updatepage.executeUpdate();
updatepage.executeBatch();
```

Comment: @Andi is your connection set in autocommit mode? If not, you will have to add `Connection#commit` after all your operations are executed.

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways, autocommit and normal, none of them worked.

Comment: Oh, I think it is working, it is taking time. I thought eclipse had crashed!

Comment: I suggest to print a message every few times (e.g. every 1000 statements set in batch) to check the progress of the batch statements (=

Answer (score -1):

Can you give paste the whole code ? From the code what you have provided updatepage.addBatch();/ updatepage.executeBatch();  is missing. Also check if dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);.